# Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react-highlight-words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a React app and I am using Hightlighter (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words) to render my autocomplete options.

```
<Highlighter searchWords={[this._input]} textToHighlight={value} />
```

Everything works great except that when value is containing html, it is not interpreted by this package (react default behaviour).

I checked documentation and the code of the react-highlight-words but I cannot find any way to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop.

Is there any other way or a suggestion that you could give me?

Thank you

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you have a solution for this?